# Installation of homebrew - confusion over version and previous installation - how do I get everything installed without warnings?

Tags: python, installation, homebrew

I have just installed homebrew and I have installed Python 3.7.5, although if I enter `python --version`, it tells me I have 3.6.4

If I use `brew info python`, it tells me I have Python 3.7.5, but a number of warnings appear. This includes unbrewed dylibs, some config files found outside my system or homebrew directories, as well as unbrewed header files, unbrewed .pc files and unbrewed static static libraries.

Running `which python` gives me `/usr/bin/python`

`Echo $PATH` gives me `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`

This is the result, I think of a previous Anaconda installation.

I want to start from scratch with a clean version of Python using homebrew.

What should I do? Any help is appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `~/.bash_profile` and set your `PATH` environment variable to:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```